# Strategy to find out how wires are connected

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory

There is a tube with $100$ electrical wires that are not labeled. 
At side $A$ of the tube, the terminal ends of the $100$ electrical wires can be connected. It is possible to connect more than $2$ terminal ends together.

For one measurement, all terminal ends can be connected at side $A$ in different nodes and one can measure the resistance (open circuit or short circuit) amongst all $100$ terminal ends at side $B$. Measuring all connectivities at side $B$ for $1$ constellation at side $A$ counts for just $1$ measurement.

How many measurements are necessary to know which terminal end  at side $A$ corresponds to which terminal end at side $A$?
What is the strategy to follow?

Comment: I'm confused. If you connect all terminal ends at side A, what are you measuring at side B?

Comment: You can measure if 2 wires are connected. Of course you will not connect all 100 wires at side A in one node, because then a measurement will reveal no information.

Comment: And all wires are initially disconnected?

Comment: You can connect different wires together at side A and you measure the resistance between each pair of terminals at side B. This way you should be able to find out which terminal at side A corresponds to which terminal at side B.

Comment: So, you create connections at side A and only measure resistance between pairs at side B?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in seven measurements. Label the wires in A from 0 to 99 iusing binary numbers.  Then for your first measurement, tie together all the A wires with a 1 in bit 0 (the odd wires).  Your measurement tells you which of the wires in B are connected to some odd wire in A.  (Because any wire in B that is connected to an odd wire in A will show a short on 49 of its tests, while any that is not will shhow open circuits on all of its tests.)

For your second measurement tie together the wires in A having bit 1 of there number equal to 1:  wires 2,3,6,7, and so forth.  Again you find out which wires in B have bit one of their partners equal to one.

Each of the wires has a 7-bit number so after measurements you now the number of the A-partner of each of the B wires.

Information theory, however, notes that each 50-tied-wires measurement gives information about which 50 B-wires are connected to one of those A-wires.  That provides $\binom{100}{50}$ possibilities, or about 96 bits of information.  Since there are $100!$ possible interconnection patterns (525 bits) one might hope there is a solution using only 6 measurements.  (The above proves that there is no solution using 5 or fewer). But the problem is, it wil take 7 measurements to determine the connection of any individual B wires, because each measurement olny gives you the answer to "is it in this set"?

So the minimum number is indeed seven measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Label the wires on one end (say end $A$) using labels $1$ to $100$.
Now, select (arbitrarily) a wire (call it $x$) on end $B$. 
The goal is to be able to which label on side $A$ does $x$ correspond to.

Connect half the wires (1 to 50) to a node.
Then you can tell if $x$ belongs to $1-50$ or $51-100$.
Proceed like this (with a bisection search) till you find the matching label for $x$.
This will take $\log_{2}100$ measurements.

Repeat for another wire at end $B$.